# Syntax error in Shader class?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have problems with compiling the program and I can't find any errors. Problematic code and error messages are presented below:

My error messages:

*- Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
   does not support default-int c:\users\codasm\desktop\nowe
   projekty\glfwframework1\system.h 9   1   GLFWFramework1*

*- Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
   '*'  c:\users\codasm\desktop\nowe
   projekty\glfwframework1\system.h 9   1   GLFWFramework1*

Error messages linking me to System.h line 9 and I don't understand what's wrong:

```
Shader* shader;
```

System.h:

```
#ifndef System_h
#define System_h

#include "Core.h"

class System
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    Shader* shader;
    // GLuint shader;
    GLenum error;
    GLuint VAO, VBO, TBO;
  vector<vec3> vertices;
    vector<vec2> uvs;
    vector<vec3> normals;
 public:
    System();
    ~System();
  bool InitWindow();
    bool InitExtensions();
    bool InitShaders();
    bool InitVertices();
    bool InitTextures();
    bool InitModels();

    void Resize(GLFWwindow* window);
    void BeginScene();
    void EndScene(GLFWwindow* window);
    void Display(GLFWwindow*);

    void Run();

    void ShutdownWindow();
    void ShutdownShaders();
    void ShutdownVertices();
    void ShutdownTextures();
};

static void KeyPress(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
static void ErrorProc(int error, const char* description);

#endif
```

Shader.cpp:

```
    #pragma once

    #include "Core.h"

    class Shader
    {
        GLuint shader;
     public:
        Shader(void);
        ~Shader(void);
        bool ConfigureShaders(string vsName, string fsName);
        void SetShaderVar(string name, mat4 MVP);

        void EnableShader(bool enable);
        GLuint GetShader();
    };
```

Shader.h:

```
#include "Shader.h"


Shader::Shader(void)
{
}


Shader::~Shader(void)
{
}

bool Shader::ConfigureShaders(string vsName, string fsName)
{
        // Wielkosc buforow na bledy moze powodowac problemy w przypadku dluzszych komunikatow
    // Utworz Shadery
    GLuint VS = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FS = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    // Czytaj Shadery
    string LineBuffer;

    fstream VSFile(vsName.c_str(),ios::in);
    string VSSource;
    if(VSFile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(VSFile,LineBuffer))
            VSSource += "\n"+LineBuffer;
        VSFile.close();
    }

    fstream FSFile(fsName.c_str(),ios::in);
    string FSSource;
    if(FSFile.is_open())
    {
        LineBuffer.clear();
        while(getline(FSFile,LineBuffer))
            FSSource += "\n"+LineBuffer;
        FSFile.close();
    }

    GLint result;
    // int infoLogLength;
    // Wprowadz, Kompiluj i Sprawdz Shadery
    char const* VSSrc = VSSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VS,1,&VSSrc,NULL);
    glCompileShader(VS);
    glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&result);
    // glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infoLogLength);

  char VSErrMsg[256];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VS,1024,NULL,VSErrMsg);
    cout<<VSErrMsg<<endl;

    char const* FSSrc = FSSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FS,1,&FSSrc,NULL);
    glCompileShader(FS);
  glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&result);
    // glGetShaderiv(VS,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infoLogLength);

  char FSErrMsg[256];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FS,1024,NULL,FSErrMsg);
    cout<<FSErrMsg<<endl;

    // Polacz Shadery
    shader = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader,VS);
    glAttachShader(shader,FS);

    glBindAttribLocation(shader,0,"vertexPos");
    glBindAttribLocation(shader,1,"vertexUV");

    glLinkProgram(shader);
    // Sprawdz Program
    glGetProgramiv(shader,GL_LINK_STATUS,&result);
    // glGetProgramiv(Shader,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infoLogLength);

    char PrgErrMsg[256];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shader,1024,NULL,PrgErrMsg);
    cout<<PrgErrMsg<<endl;

  // Kasuj Shadery
    glDeleteShader(VS);
    glDeleteShader(FS);
    return true;
}

void Shader::SetShaderVar(string name, mat4 MVP)
{
    GLuint MatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader,"MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixLocation,1,GL_FALSE,&MVP[0][0]);
}

void Shader::EnableShader(bool enable)
{
    if(!shader)
    {
        if(enable)
          glUseProgram(shader);
        else
            glUseProgram(0);
    }
}

GLuint Shader::GetShader()
{
    return shader;
}
```

Comment: Do you really `#include "Shader.h"` in `Shader.h`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I guess the labels for the last two files have been mixed up, and `"Shader.h"` is included from `"Shader.cpp"` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't declared `Shader` before using it in `System.h`. It looks like you can get away with a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

```
class Shader;
```

before the definition of `class System`, since you only need to declare a pointer to it. If you needed to do anything fancy with the class, then you'd need to include the header to get the full definition; but you don't need to here, so you shouldn't.